# How can you use a Chef recipe to set an environment variable?

Tags: environment-variables, chef-infra, chef-recipe

How can you use a Chef recipe to set an environment variable?

I need to set an environment variable using a Chef recipe. Can you provide an example of how to accomplish this?

Comment: What's the context for the environment variable you want to set?

Comment: Can you extend your question? It seems like it has been answered, unless you share more info or give us some feedback.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you need an env var set strictly within the Chef process, you can use `ENV['foo'] = 'bar`' since it's a ruby process.

If you need to set one for an [execute provider](https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html), Chef exposes an environment hash:

```
execute 'Bootstrap the database' do 
  cwd "#{app_dir}/current"
  command "#{env_cmd} rake db:drop db:create db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
  environment 'HOME' => "/home/#{app_user}"
  user app_user
  action :run
  not_if %[psql -U postgres -c "\\l" | grep #{db_name}]
end
```

If you're looking to set a persistent environment variable then you may want to have Chef edit `/etc/profile.d/chef.sh`, `/etc/environment`, a users' profile, etc.

Comment: Could you please explain how to set an environment variable permanently via chef

Comment: @Prats - check out the `magic_shell` cookbook - http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/magic_shell

Answer (score 14):

If you want to set it on the **system** with Chef, checkout the [magic_shell cookbook](https://github.com/customink-webops/magic_shell).

```
magic_shell_environment 'RAILS_ENV' do
  value 'production'
end
```

Comment: Just a note for others who are googling -- magic_shell_environment is fantastic, with one gotcha.  Any command invoked with system("/new/process/to/call") from a ruby script will not pull from /etc/profile.d/* automatically

Comment: @matt you can force that to happen by forcing an interactive login and/or sourcing `/etc/profile` in the Ruby script.

Comment: thanks, @sethvargo. To update an environment variable, such as `$PATH`, how should I use the `magic_shell` cookbook?

Comment: magic_shell_environment 'PATH' do
  value '$PATH:whatever'
end

Comment: @matt - does my problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618960/updating-path-with-magic-shell-cookbook) show a concrete example of the potential problem you mentioned?

Comment: If you're trying to roll your own installer, you might want to check out [Ark](https://supermarket.getchef.com/cookbooks/ark) instead.

Comment: @sethvargo I want to use the variable right after I set it but it is empty. next time I run the recipes, everything is fine ...!? am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @pkyeck no, that is how shell loading works. You will need to reload the shell after setting the envar.

Comment: @sethvargo Is there any way to `source` the profile file during the execution of a recipe. `execute 'source /etc/profile'` certainly doesn't work as `source` is not available in the ruby shell and it is running in a sub-shell anyway.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to set it at the system level in `/etc/environment`, you can do so directly per the following example without adding an additional recipe (this adds two env variables for Java):

```
sys_env_file = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new('/etc/environment')
{
  'JAVA_HOME' => '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64',
  'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' => '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/lib'
}.each do |name, val|
  sys_env_file.insert_line_if_no_match /^#{name}\=/, "#{name}=\"#{val}\""
  sys_env_file.write_file
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is different between Windows and Linux.  The easiest way would be:

**Windows**

Use the windows_env resource to create a System environment variable:

```
windows_env 'CHEF_LICENSE' do
  value 'accept'
end
```

**Linux**

If you only need it for the cookbook run and its children, then use the Ruby ENV resource.  This will NOT be permanent:

```
ENV['CHEF_LICENSE'] = 'accept'
```

If you need it to be permanent (and use bash):

Create a script in /etc/profile.d:

1. Create a template script (such as chef.sh.erb)
2. Fill out the template script:

   `#!/bin/bash
   export CHEF_LICENSE='accept' # Needed for Chef Infra Client 15`
3. Put the template resource in your recipe (You may want to set attributes and owner/group settings, I wanted to keep this example simple)

   `template '/etc/profile.d/chef.sh' do
      source 'chef.sh.erb'
    end`

Here are some additional resources to read up on the different resources referenced here:

[template resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html)
[windows_env resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_windows_env.html)

Comment: The Linux part was extremely helpful and worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, the best way to it is by using

```
ENV['Var'] = 'Value'
```

When you use this command, every sub process spun by the recipe will be using this ENV value. You can verify it using a bash resource and echoing the value of Var.