# How to set environment variable using Chef?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Theres a similar question to this, but cant manage it to work:
I want to simply set an env variable, then use it:

```
execute "start zookeeper" do
    cwd "/opt/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin"
    command "./zkServer.sh start"
    environment "JVMFLAGS" => "-Xmx#{heap_jvm} -Xms#{heap_jvm}"
    user "root"
    action :run
end
```

I've also tried using bash to `"export JVMFLAGS='-blabla'"` but still it runs the sh with none set to the variable. Is there some issue preventing my sh script from checking the variable?
I could use the sh like a template and replace the ocurrence of JVMFLAGS... But i want to check if theres a better solution..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried setting environment variable through Ruby just before the *execute* block? Chef actually recommends [using ENV](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_env.html) (See the *note* on that page).

```
ENV['JVMFLAGS'] = "-Xmx#{heap_jvm} -Xms#{heap_jvm}"
```

Another possibility is to add JVMFLAGS to the command itself.

```
execute "start zookeeper" do
  [...]
  command "JVMFLAGS=-Xmx#{heap_jvm} -Xms#{heap_jvm} ./zkServer.sh start"
  [...]
end
```

Comment: I tried `ENV[...]`, however after running `vagrant provision`, running `export MY_ENV_VAR` shows no variable set.

Comment: And it shouldn't be. The env variables are set only for the current process and its children.

Comment: I was looking how to set a **system** env var - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284517/how-can-you-use-a-chef-recipe-to-set-an-environment-variable/14917841#comment34443452_14917841. I had been looking for a different answer.