# Chef WARNs about setting a key when ENV is set in a recipe

Tags: chef-infra

I have a recipe that starts a service that can be configured by environment variables. Looking at how to set the variables (adding a bash script to `/etc/profile.d` didn't do the trick), I came across [How to set environment variable using Chef?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436535/how-to-set-environment-variable-using-chef) and so configured a rb file set the variables:

vars.rb:

```
ENV["foo"] = "bar"
```

myrecipe.rb:

```
require "/path/to/vars.rb"

service "someservice" do
  action :restart
end
```

When I run this, I get the following:

`WARN -- : You are setting a key that conflicts with a built-in method Hashie::Mash#default defined in Hash. This can cause unexpected behavior when accessing the key via as a property. You can still access the key via the #[] method`

Is this the best way to set variables for the service? Are the warnings acceptable? How can I get this to run cleanly?

Chef is version 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

The error means the key you are trying to set conflicts with a built-in key. Therefore, using the key afterwards would likely have unexpected results. Try using a different key name if possible.

In addition. Setting a variable in `/etc/profile.d` is for interactive shells. A service isn't running an interactive shell and therefore won't get those variables. In addition any environment variable you set in the Chef run isn't going to persist (if that's a requirement)

Assuming you are running a **systemd** system. You should set service variables using `Environment=` or `EnvironmentFile=` in your unit file. For example this is similar to something I have set up:

**someservice.service.erb**

```
[Unit]
Description=Someservice Server
After=network.target

[Service]
User=someservice
Environment="SOMESERVICE_OPTS=-someoption -someotheroption"
ExecStart=/srv/someservice/bin/someservice-server.sh run
ExecStop=/srv/someservice/bin/seomservice-server.sh stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

With Chef, I then copy this file to the correct location and make sure the systemctl daemon reloads `systemctl daemon-reload`

If this is an init based system you'll need to create an environment file somewhere and source that file in the init script like:

```
. /etc/default/someservice
<remaining init script>
```

Then make sure you use Chef to place both that environment file and the new init script on the server.

Comment: The service is not leveraging any of the standard service systems - the cookbook for the app defines it's own service handler, which basically makes the init command `appname` - so an `action :restart` results in `appname restart` being run. `appname` in /usr/local/bin is hashbanged with `#!/usr/bin/env /usr/local/openresty/bin/resty` and I am not that familiar with it - wanted to use an environment variable preferably....

Comment: You could potentially work around this by using a `bash` or `execute` resource and defining your variables in a hash with the `environment` property and run the `appname restart` command in that resource. Hard to give a better suggestion when I'm not certain how the service is being set up.

Answer (score 0):

Something that I overlooked is that the values for the variables are in a file that is only available once a resource has been processed (a bash resource that extracts a tarball). So I wouldn't even be able to access those vars in the first phase.

Instead of using vars.rb which doesn't exist at the start of the chef run, I have changed it to be a vars.sh which exports the variable, and add a notify to another bash resource with the following code:

```
bash "extract_archive" do
    code "tar zxf archive.tar.gz"
    notifies :run, "bash[restart_with_vars]", :delayed
end

bash "restart_with_vars" do
    code <<EOF
    source vars.sh
    appname restart
EOF
    action :nothing
end
```

The resolved run list has the `service "appname"` later on which starts without vars, but the bash gets added to the end of the resource list and restarts with vars.