# Can not set GOPATH with chef

Tags: linux, go, chef-infra

I am trying to use `go get` which means I have to set the go path. I have tried this through a ton of ways, so please do not mark this as a duplicate unless that solution works. I have tried almost every solution on SO I could find.

**My chef code**

```
package 'golang-go'

directory '/work-disk/go' do
  owner consul_user
  group consul_user
  mode '0755'
  action :create
end

bash 'go' do
  user consul_user
  code <<-EOH
  export GOPATH=/work-disk/go
  export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
  EOH
  action :run
end
```

I had `export GOPATH=$HOME/go` before but that seemed to fail so I created a directory to test with and explicitly said the directory but still no luck

**Error message**

```
cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
```

Comment: I know nothing about chef, but what is it actually meant to run? I fail to see how exporting two variables could result in that error message.  If the error comes from the NEXT statement in the recipe the explanation is simple; the variable gets exported, the shell that runs the following statement knows nothing about it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17436535/1153938

Comment: @tink The error is from the next resource block yes, but it should not be presenting an issue as I am running both as `consul_user` so should have access to the same exports.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how environment variables work. Setting them in a subprocess on affects that subprocess.