# Updating $PATH with `magic_shell` Cookbook

Tags: chef-infra

I created 2 cookbooks: java_kevin and maven_kevin:

**cookbooks/java_kevin/recipes/default.rb**

```ruby
node.default['user'] = 'vagrant' 
node.default['user_home'] = '/home/' + node['user'] 
node.default['my_dir'] = node['user_home'] + '/my'

node.default['vagrant'] = '/vagrant'

node.default['java_home'] = node['my_dir'] + '/jdk1.7.0_51'

# Install Java 7 RPM
execute "install_oracle_java7" do
    command "rpm -ivh --prefix=" + node['my_dir'] + " jdk-7u51-linux-x64.rpm"
    cwd node['vagrant']
    creates node['java_home']
end

magic_shell_environment 'JAVA_HOME' do 
    value node['java_home']
end 

magic_shell_environment 'PATH' do 
    value "$PATH:" + node['java_home'] + '/bin'
end
```

**cookbooks/maven_kmm/recipes/default.rb**

```ruby
node.default['user'] = 'vagrant' 
node.default['user_home'] = '/home/' + node['user'] 
node.default['my_dir'] = node['user_home'] + '/my'

node.default['maven_download_dir'] = node.default['user_home'] + '/apache-maven-3.2.1-bin.tar.gz'

# Download Maven 3.2.1
remote_file node['maven_download_dir'] do
    source "http://www.bizdirusa.com/mirrors/apache/maven/maven-3/3.2.1/binaries/apache-maven-3.2.1-bin.tar.gz"
    checksum "aaef971206104e04e21a3b580d9634fe"
end

execute "unpack_and_uncompress_maven" do
    command "tar -zxvf " + node['maven_download_dir']
    cwd node['user_home']
    creates node['user_home'] + '/apache-maven-3.2.1'
end

execute "move_maven_to_my_dir" do
    command "mv " + node['user_home'] + '/apache-maven-3.2.1' + " " + node['my_dir']
    cwd node['user_home']
    creates node['my_dir'] + '/apache-maven-3.2.1'
end

node.default['maven_home'] = node['my_dir'] + '/apache-maven-3.2.1'

magic_shell_environment 'M2_HOME' do 
    value node['maven_home']
end 

magic_shell_environment 'PATH' do 
    value "$PATH:" + node['maven_home'] + '/bin'
end
```

After provisioning, I only see that the Maven path was properly added to the `$PATH`:

```
[vagrant@vagrant-centos65 ~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/vagrant/my/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin:/home/vagrant/bin

[vagrant@vagrant-centos65 ~]$ which mvn
~/rm/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin/mvn

[vagrant@vagrant-centos65 ~]$ which java
/usr/bin/which: no java in (/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:....
```

Why was `JAVA_HOME` not part of the final `$PATH` item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that magic_shell_environment creates a unique file for each resource name (here, 'PATH' -- Check /etc/profile.d/PATH.sh) and that each time the file will be recreated.  Here both of your recipes are attempting to create the same file. And most likely the PATH.sh file created by the first recipe is getting overwritten by the second recipe.

I'm not sure how to fix this using magic_shell, but I believe that is the answer to your question "why" .

see https://github.com/customink-webops/magic_shell/blob/master/providers/environment.rb