# Set environment variables for current chef-client run

Tags: windows, powershell, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm trying to use chef to install OpenJDK, as well as downoad Eclipse and install a few plugins using p2 director on a Windows 2008 node.  OpenJDK installs and I set my environment variables JAVA_HOME and add it to the path.
 However, this change does not take affect until I close and re-open PowerShell. The chef-client run needs these in the current session to run the eclipse p2 director. Is there any way to do this so that I can run chef-client only once?

In my recipe for installing openJDK I included:

```
env "JAVA_HOME" do
  value 'C:\\Program Files\\Zulu\\zulu-8'
end

env "path" do
  delim ";"
  value '%JAVA_HOME%\\bin'
  action :modify
end

#For Command Prompt
execute "setPathCMD" do
  command "set PATH=#{node['java']['path']}\\bin;%PATH%"
end
#For PowerShell
powershell_script "setPathPS" do
  code <<-EOH
  $env:Path="#{node['java']['path']}\\bin;$env:Path"
  EOH
end

ENV['Path'] += ";C:\\Program Files\\Zulu\\zulu-8\\bin"
```

And in the recipe for installing the eclipse plugins I have:

```
if not node['eclipse']['plugins'].empty?
  node['eclipse']['plugins'].each do |plugin_group|
    repo, id = plugin_group.first
    execute "eclipse plugin install" do
      command "#{node['eclipse']['unzip_location']}/eclipse/eclipse.exe -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -noSplash -repository #{repo} -installIUs #{id}"
      action :run
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you use a Chef recipe to set an environment variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284517/how-can-you-use-a-chef-recipe-to-set-an-environment-variable)

Comment: @sethvargo Good point in general, but are you sure that the magic_shell_cookbook works in a powershell environment?

Comment: @sethvargo Had a look at the code, it will not work on Windows

Comment: You need to adapt the code for Windows. I'm sure the maintainer of the cookbook would accept a PR.

Comment: I may be wrong but don't you need to set `ENV['JAVA_HOME']` too in your openJDK recipe for the current (and child) process to know it ?

Comment: @Tensibai, in order to use it, yes, but just for the current process, I put the full path to java directly into the path. I don't have anything that uses JAVA_HOME

Comment: I had though eclipse needed a JAVA_HOME env variable to be launched...

Comment: please select the answer that worked for you

Answer (score 1):

Try using setx:

```
execute 'set java_home' do
  command "setx -m JAVA_HOME \"C:\\Program Files\\Zulu\\zulu-8\""
  only_if { ENV['JAVA_HOME'] != 'C:\\Program Files\\Zulu\\zulu-8' }
end

# Set JAVA_HOME for this process
ENV['JAVA_HOME'] = 'C:\\Program Files\\Zulu\\zulu-8'

# do something similar for path...
```

Adapted from the visualstudio cookbook for enabling NuGet package restore:
https://github.com/daptiv/visualstudio/blob/master/recipes/nuget.rb

Answer (score 0):

Put on your `client.rb` or `solo.rb`:

```
ENV['VAR'] = 'value'
```