# Chef: Setting environment variables

Tags: chef-infra

I need to set OS environment variables on my Centos/7 machine.

I've tried it using on my `variables.rb` file:

```
host = 'locahost'
port = 9201

ENV['LV_ES_HOST'] = host
ENV['LV_ES_PORT'] = '#{port}'
```

Nevertheless, on shell:

```
$ echo $LV_ES_HOST

$
```

1. How could I set an Os environment variable?
2. Could it be possible to set a OS enviroment variable only visible for an user?

I need a OS available environment variable in order for my jee applications to be able to read its value.

I'm running several jee containers on my machine, and the applications are running on need to get the LC_ES_HOST environment variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you use a Chef recipe to set an environment variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284517/how-can-you-use-a-chef-recipe-to-set-an-environment-variable)

Comment: What about user environment variables? I remember that I was able to set which environment variables a user has availaible...

Comment: Well your question start with OS env var. but they will be available to each user also. If your need is when starting a daemon there's other way but this usually depends on the target app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other question doesn't really explain the underlying problem. Unix environment variables are inherited from parent process to child process during a `fork()`. So when you set things via `ENV` in your Chef code, it does affect subprocesses that come under Chef like things run via an `execute` resource. When you log in via SSH, however, your shell is not a subprocess of `chef-client` so those variables aren't visible. Unfortunately Unix has no general purpose solution for global environment variables so you need to pick one of a number of compromises, which are listed in the other question.

Comment: What about user environment variables? I remember that I was able to set which environment variables a user has availaible...

Comment: You would have to set per-user variables in the shell init scripts for that user in their home directory.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. Nevertheless, is it able to do using chef?

Comment: Sure, those are just files so you can write them like any other file using a `template` or `file` resource.